Typescript: Correctly decide return type of a function base of its input
I have defined the input and output type like follow:
type Input = 'foo' | 'bar'

type Output = {
    'foo': string
    'bar': BarType
}

EDIT
From @jcalz's comment stated, turns out the problem is not in the function itself but from where I get data.
So here's more details:
I created a redux store:
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    bar: BarReducer
    foo: FooReducer
})

Then use it inside useData as:
    const useReduxSelector = useSelector.withTypes<RootState>()
    const {data} = useReduxSelector(state) => state[key])

Here's what I tried:
function useData<T extends Input>(key: T): Output[T] {
    const useReduxSelector = useSelector.withTypes<RootState>()
    const {data} = useReduxSelector(state) => state[key])
    return data
}

But there's an error:
Type 'string | BarType' is not assignable to type 'Output[T]'.
  Type 'BarType' is not assignable to type 'Output[T]'.
    Type 'BarType' is not assignable to type 'Account & string'.
      Type 'BarType' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Then I removed generics and tried:
function useData(key: Input): Output[Input] {
    const useReduxSelector = useSelector.withTypes<RootState>()
    const {data} = useReduxSelector(state) => state[key])
    return data
}

There's no error, but when using useData in a component, the data returned has the type string | BarType, which is not what I wanted.
What did I do wrong here?

"What did I do wrong here?" Without a [mre] instead of /** get data based on key value **/ it's not really possible for us to say. I can write that code so it works like this playground link, meaning I need to guess at what you're doing that resulted in an error. Please [edit] to provide a [mre] or this question risks being closed as needing debugging details.

@jcalz Thanks for pointing that out, I updated the question to add more context. Is the updated question enough?

Maybe? Now that your example explicitly depends on react/redux I don't know what to do with it, as I am no expert in those. If you don't get enough engagement here you might want to try to produce a standalone example. It also doesn't look like a [mre] because you're referring to things not declared (e.g., RootState).  Ideally you would put your code into a standalone IDE and fix any errors you're not asking about, so that we can all start from the same place.  Anyway, I'll disengage until and unless I see an [edit] that gives me more insight. Good luck!
